# Google Sheet formula to compile customer details and orders

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution, textjoin

I'm using Google Form and Google Sheet for my small business. I give my customers a Google Form for them to key in their name, phone number and what their orders are and I can view all my customers' orders in the Google Sheet Form Responses.

[An Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InCDj.png)

However, sometimes the items list can be too many for me to scroll to the right and left so I made a new sheet and compiled their details and orders in a single cell using the code below:

```
=FormResponses1!B2&char(10)&
FormResponses1!C2&char(10)&
IF(FormResponses1!D2>0,FormResponses1!D2&" - "&FormResponses1!D1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!E2>0,FormResponses1!E2&" - "&FormResponses1!E1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!F2>0,FormResponses1!F2&" - "&FormResponses1!F1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!G2>0,FormResponses1!G2&" - "&FormResponses1!G1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!H2>0,FormResponses1!H2&" - "&FormResponses1!H1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!I2>0,FormResponses1!I2&" - "&FormResponses1!I1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!J2>0,FormResponses1!J2&" - "&FormResponses1!J1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!K2>0,FormResponses1!K2&" - "&FormResponses1!K1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!L2>0,FormResponses1!L2&" - "&FormResponses1!L1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!M2>0,FormResponses1!M2&" - "&FormResponses1!M1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!N2>0,FormResponses1!N2&" - "&FormResponses1!N1&char(10), "")&
IF(FormResponses1!O2>0,FormResponses1!O2&" - "&FormResponses1!O1&char(10), "")&
```

it goes on for at least 60 lines of IF statements to achieve the result as in the picture below

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BQC4.png)

The issue is that when i drag the formula down the "FormResponses1!D1" (the item name) changes to "FormResponses1!D2". So i have to change them individually. Other than that it works, but i was wondering if there is an easier way to achieve the same results. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't want it to change when you drag, use `$` in front: e.g. `D$1`.

Comment: There is likely a *much* easier way to get the result you want here. It's possible that *one single formula* can return all results for all rows without dragging. If you are interested in exploring that, share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to not change the frame of reference use `$` in front of either column or row or both:

```
$D1
D$1
$D$1
```

<kbd>F4</kbd> is the shortcut

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B&CHAR(10)&C2:C&CHAR(10)&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(D2:Z="",,D2:Z&"×-×"&SUBSTITUTE(D1:Z1, " ", "×"))),,9^9))), " ", CHAR(10)), "×", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this into a script, you can use the code below.
It will change the formatting to look more like the image below, which I find more appealing. If you do use this option, don't forget to change the "numberOfItems" value.

[image: mock script result]

```
function ConsolidateInfoTwo() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET_NAME');
  let sheetDB = sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  let numberOfItems = 20; //Change this to however many you have
  let categoryAray = sheet.getRange(1,3,1,(numberOfItems+2)).getValues();
  let itemCategories = categoryAray[0];

for (i=0;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++)
 {
   var info = "";
   let currentData = sheetDB[i];
     for (h=0;h<(numberOfItems+2);h++) 
     {
         if (currentData[h] != '')
         {
        //If you don't want the items to come out as "Item 1: 3", you can change the order here
        info += (itemCategories[h]+": "+currentData[h] + "\n");
         }
      sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(info);
    }
  }
}
```